# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 11 validation errors for For Trip type=value_error.missing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

Im getting this error with my pydantic schema, but oddly it is generating the object correctly, and sending it to the SQLAlchemy models, then it suddenly throws error for all elements in the model.

```
response -> id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> date
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> time
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> price
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> distance
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> origin_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> destination_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> driver_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> passenger_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> vehicle_id
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
response -> status
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

i must say that all the fields should have values. And the error trace do not references any part of my code so i dont even know where to debug. Im a noob in SQLAlchemy/pydantic

here are some parts of the code

```
class Trip(BaseModel):
    id: int
    date: str
    time: str
    price: float
    distance: float
    origin_id: int
    destination_id: int
    driver_id: int
    passenger_id: int
    vehicle_id: int
    status: Status

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

```
class TripDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'trip'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    time = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    price = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    distance = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String(64), nullable=False)

    origin_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('places.id'), nullable=False)
    destination_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('places.id'), nullable=False)

    origin = relationship("PlaceDB", foreign_keys=[origin_id])
    destination = relationship("PlaceDB", foreign_keys=[destination_id])

    driver_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('driver.id'), nullable=False)
    vehicle_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('vehicle.id'), nullable=False)
    passenger_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('passenger.id'), nullable=False)
```

```
def create_trip(trip: Trip, db: Session):
    origin = db.query(models.PlaceDB).filter(models.PlaceDB.id == trip.origin_id).first()
    destination = db.query(models.PlaceDB).filter(models.PlaceDB.id == trip.destination_id).first()
    db_trip = TripDB(
        id=(trip.id or None),
        date=trip.date or None, time=trip.time or None, price=trip.price or None, 

    distance=trip.distance or None, 
            origin_id=trip.origin_id or None, destination_id=(trip.destination_id or None), status=trip.status or None, 
            driver_id=trip.driver_id or None, passenger_id=trip.passenger_id or None, vehicle_id=trip.vehicle_id or None, origin=origin, destination=destination)
    try:
        db.add(db_trip)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_trip)
        return db_trip

    except:
        return "Somethig went wrong"
```

Comment: Have you checked the return of your db? Are you sure you don't pass in the final `except` of the `create_trip` function ?

Comment: the return is OK, I've managed to "fix" it, removing the pydantic model from the create trip funcion, i know it's probably wrong but it works, with some manual type checks it should run without any problems... the funny thing is apparently it never got into the create_trip function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bug on the pydantic model, it happened to me as well, and i was not able to fix it, but indeed if you just skip the type check in the route it works fine

Comment: How does one skip the type check in the route?

Comment: @FrankHarrison Assigning a type for everything fixed it for me. `@app.post("/loc", response_class=PlainTextResponse, status_code=201)`
`def event_serialized_json_uploaded(uploaded_json: dict):`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is a conflict in your schema and `create_trip` function. Have you checked whether you are passing the correct param to your schema? You have defined most of the fields as not nullable, and you are passing None as an alternative value in `db.add()` command.

I had a similar problem with my code, and I figured that naming and type convention between schema and server.py. After matching the field names and type in both file, I resolved the error of the field required (type=value_error.missing).

```
# project/schema.py
from pydantic import BaseModel

# here I had made mistake by using target_URL in server.py
# variable name and type should be same in both schema and server
class URLBase(BaseModel):
    target_url: str


class URL(URLBase):
    is_active: bool
    clicks: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class URLInfo(URL):
    url: str
    admin_url: str
```

```
# project/server.py
@app.post('/url', response_model=schema.URLInfo)
def create_short_url(url: schema.URLBase, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if not validators.url(url.target_url):
        raise bad_request_message(message="Your provided URL is not valid!")
    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    key = "".join(secrets.choice(chars) for _ in range(5))
    secret_key = "".join(secrets.choice(chars) for _ in range(8))
    db_url = models.URL(target_url=url.target_url, key=key, secret_key=secret_key)
    db.add(db_url)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_url)
    db_url.url = key
    db_url.admin_url = secret_key

    return db_url
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check the return statement, i had similar issue and got the issue reolved by correcting my return statement. I see return statement missing or wrong in create_trip function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).